# Python Django: Generate table from SQLite to code in models.py bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

**I create table in SQLite and generate code to models.py by cmd: python manage.py inspect > home/models.py, but I can't runserver and have this bug. Please help me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

```
PS E:\Code\Python\demoWeb> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run 
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 851, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 988, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 918, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Comment: What is inside models.py? Have you restarted the devserver?

Comment: nothing inside models.py, but when I inspectdb > home/models.py, have code of SQLite table in model, but UTF8 change to UTF-16le, I think it can be bug..

Comment: It may be due to [powershell encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_character_encoding?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: how I solve it :(( Im trying use mysql to config utf-8 but can't fix it..

Comment: Read the above link, under the section 'Changing the default encoding'. Change powershell's encoding to the one you want. e.g. $PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'. After changing it, re-directing to file should use the new encoding.